# Why I'm not getting CNAME records from Blogger?

Tags: dns, blogger, google-blogger-api

I'm setting up my custom domain with Blogger and from tutorials I can see
Blogger should be giving CNAME records upon entering custom domain.

That isn't happening. Has Blogger changed how this is done ? The tutorials
are only about a year old.

[image]

Thank you for enlightening me.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late with the answer, but maybe this will help someone else reaching this.

I had the same issue, I guess because I used Gmail with my custom domain, so it was already registerd and verfied with Google through the MX record.

What you need to do is go to [Google's Webmaster](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification), there you can see all your Google registered domains (make sure you are logged in to your Google account). Than:

- Click on the domain you want
- Now you can see if and how it is verified
- If needed, to add a CNAME record click "Verify using a different method"
- Choose your DNS provider
- Make sure the record type is set to CNAME, if not click "Add a CNAME record" at the bottom
- Use label/host field as record name and destination/target as record value

Make sure to also add the global Google CNAME record:

- record name: **blog.my-domain.com** (Your unique domain)
- record value: **ghs.google.com** (Google's global value)

Worth mentioning that it takes some time for the records to set.